# Adding custom post type to count in category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm working on building a section for related posts in my theme's `single.php` file and I'm querying things based on the count returned from `count` (returned from `get_the_category($post->ID);`)

The only problem is that count is only including posts, and I have another post type called `multimedia` I want included in the count.

I've already added the following to my `function.php` file:

```
<?php 
//...

/**
 * Add multimedia / video reports to news listings
 */
function add_multimedia_to_tax( $query ) {
  if ( is_category() || is_tag() &&
       empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters']) ) {

    // Get regular posts and mulimedia
    $post_types = array( 'post', 'multimedia' );

    $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );

    return $query;
  }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_multimedia_to_tax' );
```

This makes multimedia show up in my category and tag archives as expected but the count is still off.  For example, in one category I have 3 post and 2 multimedia articles, for a total of five articles but `$categories[0]->count` is still showing 3.

How can I go about this? I'd really rather not make a new query just to get a count. (If possible I'd like to have this in `functions.php` and change the category count across the entire site.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code let me know if you are facing any issues in it.

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'jobs' )->publish;
```

Comment: How does that help get the number of posts in a particular taxonomy? That will just return all the posts for that CPT :/